# Indenting a column in excel

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I am a VBA novice and am trying to "automate" a repetitive task within an excel spreadsheet. Am trying to indent a column based upon outline levels in a different column. I've been attempting to adapt code from a similar task but have run into a wall. Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is have the macro read down the OutLvl column and indent the next column based upon the outline level. Below is a screen shot of this macro and highlighted in yellow is where it got hung up. Any opinions or feedback is appreciated as I am trying to learn the application. Thanks!
[Indent Macro Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYSS9.png)

Comment: Post your code in your question, not a screenshot :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks here like you are not properly initializing the range that you intend to iterate over.  The `Range` object is tricky, in that it can actually refer to a group of cells itself, and the array usage here is unnecessary and even confusing.  Try something like this:

```
Dim OutLvl as Range ' This will refer to the whole range of interest
Dim t as Range      ' Always good practice to declare all variables
...   ' Fill in the code as you have written
Set OutLvl = Range("A1:A20")    ' Now OutLvl refers to A1:A20 on the active sheet.
    'Note that I can't possibly know how to appropriately set this range.

For Each t in OutLvl
    ...  ' Now perform the loop as you have written
Next t
```

More on the error you have received.  Note I have not watched this, so I can't speak for its accuracy:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWT2YfSHpfM